# Heroku and Circle CI 2.0 Authentication with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, circleci

I'm trying to migrate from Circle CI 1.0 to 2.0 and it seems to be a real pain.

I have the following config for Circle 2.0:

> - steps:
>
>   - checkout
>   - run: bundle exec wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
>   - run: heroku scale worker=0 --app xxxx-yyy
>   - run: "[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
>   - run: git push git@heroku.com:xxxx-yyy.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
>   - run: heroku run rake db:migrate --app xxxx-yyy

And the for the most part, it works. It will go through these commands - however when interacting with Heroku I receive these errors:

> Scaling dynos... !
>    ▸    Invalid credentials
>    ▸    provided.
>   heroku: Enter your login credentials
>   Email: Scaling dynos... !
>    ▸    Invalid credentials
>    ▸    provided.
>   Enter your Heroku credentials:
>   Email:

It's odd because on the 1.0 branch, I can scale Heroku and run db:migrate without any need for additional config.

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CircleCI docs for both 1.0 and 2.0 indicate they expect you to be configuring a Heroku API key:

Excerpt of the 2.0 instructions:

`Add the name of your Heroku application and your Heroku API key as environment variables. See Adding Project Environment Variables for instructions. In this example, these variables are defined as HEROKU_APP_NAME and HEROKU_API_KEY, respectively.
...
git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git master`

Source: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/#heroku

Personally I've also used SSH keys but using the API key approach looks pretty explicit and straightforward.